# getting error ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -t//--template, -i//--images

Tags: python-3.x

whenever I was trying to run the code i am getting error

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -t/ TEMPLATE -i/ IMAGES [-v VISUALIZE]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -t//--template, -i//--images

import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import glob
import cv2
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\D\Desktop")

## construct the argument parser and parse the arguments

try:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-t", "--template", required=True, help=  "testing.jpeg" )
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
help="intel.jpeg")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--visualize",
help="Flag indicating whether or not to visualize each iteration")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print("Ok")
template = cv2.imread(args["template"])
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("Template", template)
```

except:

```
print("Error is here")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code and the error, I deduct you are running the code in iPython notebook. If that's the case, try the following setting your args in args array:

```
args = vars(ap.parse_args(args=[]))
```